# htaccess Redirect to page if subpage starts with $

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect to a specific page (and add the subpage as a param) if the subpages starts with $
so the url:

```
https://example.com/$KD3442D
```

I'd like to redirect to :

```
https://example.com/home?pin=$KD3442D
```

and only if the subpage (in the above example $KD3442D) starts with $. 
For all other subpages I'd like the existing rule to be active.

Existing htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `home.php` in site root directory?

Answer (score 0):

I added rewrite rule for $ requests

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^\$(.*)$ /home?pin=$$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: the above solution doesn't seem to have any effect